# Is this an admissible singular value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to check if the following is an admissible SVD of the matrix:

$$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        3 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 3 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$ U =  \left(\begin{matrix}
        \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
        \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
\Sigma =     \left(\begin{matrix}
        2\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
        \sqrt{10} & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
V^T =     \left(\begin{matrix}
        \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\
        -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & 0 \\
        -\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{30}} & -\frac{5}{\sqrt{30}} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

OR does $\Sigma$ have to be a square matrix?

Comment: $Σ$ being square and $V$ rectangular is also a valid version of the SVD. What to use depends on the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 
$$
\Sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2\sqrt 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{10} & 0
\end{array} \right )
$$
but besides that you found it right. All you have to do is check if
$$
A = U \Sigma V^T
$$
which is true with the correction above.